# flutter add value to list

Tags: flutter, dart

i set object like this : {"name":"alex","code":"123"}
into sharedPrefrence Calss A:

```
            var resBody = {};
            resBody["name"] = name.text;
            resBody["code"] = pass.text;
            str = json.encode(resBody);
            print(str);
            SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
            prefs.setString("list_customer", str);
```

and when get this sharedPrefrence in another class 
add value of shared to the list Class B:

```
    customer = (prefs.getString('list_customer'));
     Map<String, dynamic> user = jsonDecode(customer);
    _customer.nameFamily = user['name'];
    _customer.code = user['code'];
    _list.add(_customer);
```

and i want to know how can i set new value of shared into the previous list like this : 
[{"name":"alex","code":"123"},{"name":"john","code":"128"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store multiple customers, you need a `List` not `Map`.

1. Declare a `List`

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> customers = [];
```

2. Add object(s) to the list

```dart
final customer = {
  "name": name.text,
  "code": pass.text,
};

customers.add(customer);
```

3. Stringfy (encode) `customers` list

```dart
final customersString = json.encode(customers);
```

4. Store encoded `customers` list

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("list_customer", customersString);
```

---

Let's say you store one customer, and now you need to store another.

1. we get `customers` list first, then we decode it

```dart
String customersString = await prefs.getString('list_customer');
final customers = json.decode(customersString);
```

2. Add the new object to the list (previous step #2)

```dart
customers.add({
  "name": 'Amir',
  "code": 'SWF2022',
});
```

3. Repeat step #3 and #4.

Good luck

Comment: i have error when decode : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: I have updated the answer, just use `final customers` instead of `List<Map<String, dynamic>> customers` when decoding.

Comment: when i back to setString page ,new data replace to past data . i want to keep last item and new data add to last item

Comment: You may post a new question for that then send me the link to check it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60590987/flutter-add-value-of-sharedprefrence-to-list

Answer (score 0):

Check example below

```
Future saveGetValues() async {
    const key = 'list_customer';
    var list = <Map<String, String>>[];
    list.add(createValue('name1', 'code2'));

    //save first time
    save(key, list);
    list = await getValue<List<Map<String, String>>>(key); //here your saved list

    //add second value
    list.add(createValue('name2', 'code2'));
    save(key, list);

    list = await getValue<List<Map<String, String>>>(key); //here your saved list with two items
  }

  Map<String, String> createValue(String name, String code) {
    final resBody = <String, String>{};
    resBody["name"] = name;
    resBody["code"] = code;
    return resBody;
  }

  Future save(String key, dynamic value) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(key, jsonEncode(value));
  }

  Future<T> getValue<T>(String key) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return json.decode(prefs.getString(key)) as T;
  }
```