# flutter add value of sharedPrefrence to list

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to add name and code to sharedPrefrence and list them 
and another class use this shared , then when back to setString Page i want to keep first name and code value and new name and code add to later list (: 
my setString :

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> customers = [];
final customer = {
"name": name.text,
"code": pass.text,
};
customers.add(customer);
final customersString = json.encode(customers);
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString("list_customer", customersString);
```

my getString :

```
String customersString = await prefs.getString('list_customer');
List<dynamic> customers=[]
final customers = json.decode(customersString);
```

Comment: I suggest [pref_dessert](https://pub.dev/packages/pref_dessert) package with [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable). You can store any object in shared preferences.

Comment: State management  doc: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt

Comment: Post the code of the pages that use `setString` and `getString`